# Creating a decorator to mock input() using monkeypatch in pytest

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, decorator

End goal: I want to be able to quickly mock the `input()` built-in function in pytest, and replace it with an iterator that generates a (variable) list of strings.  This is my current version, which works:

```py
from typing import Callable
import pytest


def _create_patched_input(str_list: list[str]) -> Callable:
    str_iter = iter(str_list.copy())

    def patched_input(prompt: str) -> str:  # has the same signature as input
        val = next(str_iter)
        print(prompt + val, end="\n"),
        return val

    return patched_input


@pytest.fixture
def _mock_input(monkeypatch, input_string_list: list[str]):
    patched_input = _create_patched_input(input_string_list)
    monkeypatch.setattr("builtins.input", patched_input)


def mock_input(f):
    return pytest.mark.usefixtures("_mock_input")(f)

# Beginning of test code
def get_name(prompt: str) -> str:
    return input(prompt)


@mock_input
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "input_string_list",
    (["Alice", "Bob", "Carol"], ["Dale", "Evie", "Frank", "George"]),
)
def test_get_name(input_string_list):
    for name in input_string_list:
        assert get_name("What is your name?") == name
```

However, this feels incomplete for a few reasons:

- It requires the parameter name in the `parameterize` call to be `input_string_list`, which feels brittle.
- If I move the fixtures into another function, I need to import both `mock_input` and `_mock_input`.

What would feel correct to me is to have a decorator (factory) that can be used like `@mock_input(strings)`, such that you could use it like

```py
@mock_input(["Alice", "Bob", "Carol"])
def test_get_name():
    ....
```

or, more in line with my use case,

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "input_list", # can be named whatever
    (["Alice", "Bob", "Carol"], ["Dale", "Evie", "Frank", "George"]),
)
@mock_input(input_list)
def test_get_name():
    ....
```

The latter I don't think you can do, as pytest wont recognize it as a fixture. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: I'd rather use indirect parametrization on the `_mock_input` fixture, since it needs parameters anyway.

Comment: @hoefling Can you show what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use indirect parametrization for `mock_input`, since it cannot work without receiving parameters. Also, I would refactor `mock_input` into a fixture that does passing through the arguments it receives, performing the mocking on the way. For example, when using `unittest.mock.patch()`:

```
import pytest
from unittest.mock import patch

@pytest.fixture
def inputs(request):
    texts = requests.param  # ["Alice", "Bob", "Carol"] etc
    with patch('builtins.input', side_effect=texts):
        yield texts
```

Or, if you want to use `monkeypatch`, the code gets a bit more complex:

```
@pytest.fixture
def inputs(monkeypatch, request):
    texts = requests.param
    it = iter(texts)

    def fake_input(prefix):
        return next(it)

    monkeypatch.setattr('builtins.input', fake_input)
    yield texts
```

Now use `inputs` as test argument and parametrize it indirectly:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    'inputs',
    (["Alice", "Bob", "Carol"], ["Dale", "Evie", "Frank", "George"]),
    indirect=True
)
def test_get_name(inputs):
    for name in inputs:
        assert get_name("What is your name?") == name
```